# Multiple Apple Developer Accounts

Tags: apple-id, app-store-connect

I've read multiple messages on the subject, but I wondered if anyone had first hand experience (or genuine knowledge one way or another), if it is possible to more than one Apple Developer account?

As far as I know, you can create one for each Apple ID that you have, but I have not been able to find anything that suggests this is not possible (or breaches any rules). Are Apple likely to be bothered as long as you pay the $99/year for each Developer Account?

There is a link [here](https://www.quora.com/Does-Apple-allow-people-to-create-multiple-developer-accounts) that seems to suggest that it is possible

Would appreciate any comments on the subject.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're trying to validate a solution.  What is the actual issue you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 5):

## Business Entities and Individuals

If you operate a legally recognised business entity, the business can have an account and you can have a personal account. You will need to associate each account with a separate e-mail address.

### Consultants and Clients

If you are a consultant, you should consider one account for yourself and one each for your clients.

### Personal Experience

I use multiple Apple Developer Accounts. They are associated either with business entities I am associated with, or are personal developer accounts.

As you mention, each account needs to pay the annual fee.

Comment: Thank you. When you say you use multiple Developer accounts, are they in your own (personal) name, or business names? Thank you.

Comment: Businesses names and one in my own name. I do not believe Apple care about the number of personal accounts you are willing to pay for.

Comment: Hi! Is it possible to [add alternative email addresses](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201356) and create a business developer account with the already registered personal developer account under one apple id? I already have a personal developer account, and need to create a developer business account for a company. Can I create it with the company's email address (@company.com) that I have, by [adding](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201356) it to my icloud account, and then later handing over the account (the business developer account) to the company?

Comment: @mk117 please could you [ask a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as yours involves moving existing Apple ID addresses to new accounts. I think it is worth asking separately to attract answers from those who may have done this before.

Comment: Ok. Although the question is similar cause I have 2 email addresses and need to know if I can use them separately with a single iCloud account

Comment: No problem. Be aware that comments are effectively invisible on Stack Exchange web sites. The best way to attract attention is to ask a new question; even if it gets marked as duplicate you can argue your situation is different. See https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/how-to-address-follow-on-questions

Comment: Ok. I've posted the question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/362480/115622)